# How to get node with specific conditions in the nodes on the same level

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes

XML is:

```
<table class="list members">
  <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="member-141568" class="odd member">
        <td class="name user">
          <td class="roles">
            <td class="buttons">
      </tr>
      <tr id="member-141576" class="even member">
        <td class="name user">
          <td class="roles">
            <td class="buttons">
      </tr>
      <tr id="member-141573" class="odd member">
        <td class="name user">
          <a class="user active" href="/users/144550">Kay Kay</a>
        </td>
        <td class="roles">
          <td class="buttons">
            <a class="icon icon-edit" onclick="$('#member-141573-roles').hide(); $('#member-141573-roles-form').show(); return false;; return false;" href="#">Edit</a>
            <a class="icon icon-del" href="/memberships/141573" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" data-remote="true">Delete</a>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The main idea is to get Edit button for specific user in the list on site. 
So how to get "Edit" element (`//a[@class="icon icon-edit" and text()='Edit']`) for specific user (`//a[@class="user active" and text()="Kay Kay"]`)?

Answer (score 1):

Q: *to get Edit button for specific user*
I think it should be:

```
//tr[.//a[@class='user active' and text()='Kay Kay']]//a[@class='icon icon-edit' and text()='Edit']
```

Find the tr with the user:

```
 //tr[.//a[@class='user active' and text()='Kay Kay']]
```

and the edit button inside this tr:

```
 //a[@class='icon icon-edit' and text()='Edit']
```

Update:

Thanks to **har07 first right answer** I added one dot (`.`) to above tr expression.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the two expressions, you gonna need to find a nearest common ancestor first, in this case the `tr` element :

```
//tr[.//a[@class='user active' and text()='Kay Kay']]
```

The above should find `tr` element that contains certain user. Notice that the `.` before `/` in the predicate expression *is required* to make it relative to current `tr` context. Furthermore, since `a` is not too deeply nested, I'd suggest to use a full path. It would make the XPath *a bit* more efficient while keeping the expression about equally concise :

```
//tr[td/a[@class='user active' and text()='Kay Kay']]
```

Then, from this `tr`, continue the path to return the target element using your 2nd XPath :

```
//a[@class="user active" and text()="Kay Kay"]
```

The following would be the entire XPath that I would be using for this task :

```
//tr[td/a[@class="user active" and .="Kay Kay"]]//a[@class='icon icon-edit' and .='Edit']
```

Comment: It helped! Thank you very much!